# The settings for connecting mysql database in django settings

Tags: python-3.x, django, mysql-workbench

"django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1698, "Access denied for user 'root'@'lkocalhost'")"
When trying to manage.py runserver, The error above keeps popping up that access denied for me to connect mysql to my django project.

functionality of local host

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a 'k' in your settings. It should be 'localhost' if the database is on the same computer as the django application.